# Generating a random number from 0-9 in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a Windows batch file that will generate a random number from 0 to 9 and then load a different map list in our game server based on the random number.

I have tried to modify a similar file that was on this forum for generating random characters, but when I reduce the maxchars variables to 1 in length.

I sometimes get `@echo is off` as a response and sometimes get a number.

Here's what I have:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Random.bat
REM
REM Change these values to whatever you want, or change the code to take them
REM as command-line arguments.  You must set CHARS_LEN to the string length
REM of the string in the CHARS variable.
REM 
REM This script generates a string of these characters at least
REM MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE chars long and at most MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE chars long.

SET CHARS=0123456789
SET /A CHARS_LEN=10 + 10 + 10
SET /A MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE=1
SET /A MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE=2

REM Pick a random line length and output a random character until we reach that
REM length.

call:rand %MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE% %MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE%
SET /A LINE_LENGTH=%RAND_NUM%

SET LINE=
    for /L %%a in (1 1 %LINE_LENGTH%) do (
    call:rand 1 %CHARS_LEN%
    SET /A CHAR_INDEX=!RAND_NUM! - 1
    CALL SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=%%CHARS:~!CHAR_INDEX!,1%%
    SET LINE=!LINE!!EXTRACTED_CHAR!    
)
echo !LINE!

goto:EOF

REM The script ends at the above goto:EOF.  The following are functions.

REM rand()
REM Input: %1 is min, %2 is max.
REM Output: RAND_NUM is set to a random number from min through max.
:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto:EOF

:eof
```

Once I can get this reliably choosing characters I just need to add a selection process to the end which will call the server with a different command line for each map list.

Comment: I think you missed the "@echo off" which will turn echo off and command output will show

Answer (score 4):

The LastStar007 method works great for values between 0 and 9. For a more generic solution that returns a pseudo random number between 0 and *n*, simply use SET /A to get %random% modulo (n+1).

For example, to get a random number between 0 and 9 on the command line, use

```
set /a "rand=%random% % 10"
```

If used in a batch file then the modulo operator must be doubled

```
set /a "rand=%random% %% 10"
```

Comment: Yes, the double quotes were the problem for me. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the random string in `SET` and then lop off everything but the last character.

```
    SET RAND=%RANDOM:~-1%
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem still persists, try the following. It generates a number between `a` and `b`. Tweak it to your needs:

```
@echo off   
color 02  
echo enter value of A  
set  /p a=  
echo.  
echo  enter value of B  
set /p b=  
:main  
set no=%random%  
if  %no% GEQ %a% goto sub  
if not %no% GEQ %a% goto  main  
:sub  
if %no% LEQ  %b% goto end  
if not %no% LEQ  %b% goto  main  
:end      
echo %no%  
goto main
```